# Small Mac Server Overwrites Permissions when Saving Directly to the Server

Tags: permission, osx-server

I have instances where I have files open on Photoshop and if I try to save them my Permissions are revoked I have to manually go change the read/Write permissions for that Enclosing folder and apply to all enclosed but as soon as someone els or me Saves the File again it goes back to revoking permissions.

Both of us use the same user that has the server OS on it to do this. This wasnt a Issue previously but Something im running into now. Not sure if anyone can walk me through why this would happen? Or maybe a better way to setup an Account for us to use to Read/Write Without being able to change permissions as well

Comment: [Photoshop is notorious for this](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/editing-files-from-photoshop-to-smb-share/td-p/10233960) - any chance you could do the work locally and have finder save it to the server?

Comment: I usually Just make a local copy Work and save copy it back onto the server the other tends to open/save/work from the server folder which I think is the issue . It is refreshing to know That Photoshop has related issue as its the only application i have issues with. I'll look into this from the Photoshop angle then

Comment: Save in background can cause a lot of pain too - https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/saving-images.html it should only take you 30 minutes to review the save options in photoshop unless there’s debate on the team what set of preferences they want to agree on…

Comment: That is something I have tried disabling before I figured that would be the cause initially its just a very odd scenario as its not a guaranteed occurrence it can happen to a file that has been opened 10 times prior that day